# public web service

Tags: spring, spring-security, cxf

I wrote a web service with cxf also in my project I use spring. If someone wants to access my service, he/she gets error "Fault occurred while processing". It s about spring security. I want that my service is public and everybody access how can i configure it.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried spring security intercept url? the config likes look following

```
<security:http ......
<security:intercept-url pattern="/yourwebservice/**"
filters="none" />
</security:http>
```

With this config, web service call should bypass spring security.

Comment: could you attach the full exception trace as well as your spring security config.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean

Comment: when the web service clients get "Fault occurred while processing", there must be an exception thrown at server side. Do you have the exception detail, since apparently **Fault occurred while processing** is not root exception.